# Syntax error, IDK where?

Tags: php, html, mysql, insert

```
<?php
include("../package/mysql-connect.php");      //connect- succeeds

          //cleanin' data
$username = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']));

$password = hash('sha512', $passround);

$fname = ucfirst(trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fname'])));
$lname = ucfirst(trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lname'])));
$gender = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['gender']);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$bio = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['bio']);
$interests = str_replace(',',':',mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['interests']));

      //the query - error is here i think O. o
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `kapip_data`.`userdata` (`id`, `username`, `password`, `fname`, `lname`, `gender`, `hidden`, `hide-gender`, `hide-name`, `bio`, `interests`, `email`) VALUES (NULL, $username, $password, $fname, $lname, $gender, '0', '0' , '0', $bio, $interests, $email)") or die(mysql_error());

      //close connection- succeeds
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

This keeps saying:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
>       to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use 
>       near '(interests show here), (email shows here))' at line 1.

The strange thing is, all of my data is escaped and formatted properly. I can't seem to find my error, if I'm just tired is all. Also, does the "@" sign in emails have anything to do with the failure to insert?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please always show the finished query.

In this case however, the reason is easy to spot: You are missing quotes around your arguments.

Do

```
 VALUES (NULL, '$username', '$password', '$fname', .......
```

Comment: Scroll over, it's a long query, haha :D

Comment: @Ken no problem. (By "finished query" I mean the final result after PHP has inserted the variables - it always helps to see that as well.)

Comment: Oh, sorry, and 

@MC Emperor You do know there is a time-limit to accept answers?

Comment: I didn't know (its a mimimum of 15 minutes, I see). Sorry. ;-)